# How to get join attributes in CDbCriteria in YII?

Tags: php, yii, cactivedataprovider

In company model I get joining models user and business_unit.

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
$criteria->compare('status',$this->status);

$criteria->condition = "`t`.status = '1'";
$criteria->order = 'created DESC';
$criteria->join = " inner join  users on users.company_id = `t`.id";

$criteria->condition = "`t`.status = '1'";
$criteria->order = 'created DESC';
$criteria->join = " inner join  business_unit on business_unit.company_id = `t`.id";
```

It works. But I get only company attributes.How I get `business_unit` and `users` attributes along with `company` attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create relations in "company" models for users and business_unit, such as :

1) The first thing is to check if you have the two relations in Company models, for users and business_unit:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'users' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'User', 'company_id'),
        'businessUnits' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'BusinessUnit', 'company_id'),
    );
}
```

2) Then you can create criteria with:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
$criteria->compare('status',$this->status);
$criteria->with = array('users', 'businessUnits');
$criteria->together = true;
```

3) To have all models:

```
$models = Company::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Then for each model you have users and business unit:

```
foreach($models as $m)
{
     // Users
     $users = $m->users;
     $bu = $m->businessUnit;
}
```

4) To have active data provider:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Company', array('criteria' => $criteria);
```

Comment: Thanks it works...Just one more thing how I get nested join attributes

Comment: In foreach cycling each relation (because relations are has_many)